# PHP code filter in Nanoc's HAML code

Tags: php, syntax, haml, contact-form, nanoc

I wanted to make a contact form at my nanoc site and I need to put some php code in my `.haml` file - is there any way (filter maybe?) to easily achieve that or I have to save whole page as a `.php` (and with stantard html syntax instead of haml one?).

Or maybe there is pure Ruby solution(which can be achieved when hosting on github?)

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haml 3.2 is due to be released soon (rc3 has just been [released](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haml/m3mFOsT_s08)), and there should be a new [`haml-contrib`](https://github.com/haml/haml-contrib) gem released along with it. `haml-contrib` has a [PHP filter](https://github.com/haml/haml-contrib/blob/master/lib/haml/filters/php.rb) that might be what you’re looking for.

The doc comment for the php filter says:

```
# A PHP Filter for Haml. This simply wraps code inside <?php ?> tags. While this
# may seem like a strange idea, some people use Haml to generate mostly static
# HTML documents that then include small amounts of PHP.
#
# This code also serves as an example of how to implement a simple filter for
# Haml.
```

It doesn’t really do much more than the `:plain` filter in [Kevin Granger’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14575116/214790), but might make things slightly easier.

An example:

```
$ cat php.haml 
:php
  foreach ($es as $e) {
    echo $e;
  }
$ haml -rhaml/filters/php php.haml 
<?php
  foreach ($es as $e) {
    echo $e;
  }
?>
```

Comment: are you aware of examples that let you do anything more than a plain filter? e.g. assign the output of haml code to a PHP variable?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the :plain filter to preserve the php, it does not parse the filtered text. This is useful when you to keep multiple line of php.

ex:

```
:plain
  <?php foreach ($es as $e) {
    echo $e;
  } ?>
```